# A question regarding the inverse of continuous mappings.

Tags: analysis

> 1. If there is a continuous mapping $f:\Bbb{R^2}\to\Bbb{R}$, will $f^{-1}$ also be continuous?
> 2. If there is a differentiable mapping $g:\Bbb{R^2}\to\Bbb{R}$, will $g^{-1}$ be continuous/differentiable?

I don't know how to proceed here. To show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous, we will have to show that the inverse of every open set is an open set. How will we form open sets in $\Bbb{R^2}$ for $f^{-1}$? Do we only consider open sets in $\Bbb{R^2}$ whose elements are fibers of points in $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: If $f^{-1}$ were continuous, $f$ would be a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$.  Does this seem possible?  What sorts of properties of topological spaces are preserved under homeomorphism?

Comment: If $g^{-1}$ exists, then $g$ is injective.  Can you think of a differentiable injection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: For 2. If you want to apply the inverse function theorem, one more condition needed: the Jacobian matrix $Dg(x_0)$ is invertible $\forall x_0 \in \mathbb{R^2}$. Then $g^{-1}$ exists and is of class $C^1$.

Comment: @Mark- I think the inverse function theorem is applicable only for $\Bbb{R^n}\to\Bbb{R^n}$. The exponent $n$ has to be the same.

Comment: Yes, thank you @freebird. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

There can be not just no continuous invertible map (bijection) $f$ of $\mathbb R^2$ onto $\mathbb R$ , as Eric Towers pointed out, but not even a continuous map with continuous inverse *into* $\mathbb R$ (i.e. you can't even have a local bijection): Consider a compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb R^2$, then its image is ,as a subspace, Hausdorff, i.e.,$f|_K: \rightarrow f(K)$ is a continuous bijection between compact and Hausdorff, which is a homeomorphism . This is not possible by, e.g., Invariance of Domain. Since continuous local bijection is not possible, differentiable is not possible either.